# Can I travel with an expired German resident card?

Tags: passports, peru, paraguay

I have been living in Germany since 2010 with a permanent residence card, which must be renewed every 2 years.

My passport expired in August, so the same happened with my residence card, because of the bureaucracy of my country I requested the new passport in advance (end of April) but am still waiting and **the embassy just put a stamp on my old expired passport making it valid for another year**

Germany is waiting for the new pass (is a new pass number) to give me a new residence card for another 2 year.

Can I go in December for Christmas to Peru and Paraguay and then come back to Germany with no immigration issues?

Comment: I think the answer is simply "No". As far as coming to Europe is concerned, the best case scenario is getting some sort of visa or reentry permit if you can't renew your resident card in time but you would still need a passport to put it in, board the plane, etc. and Germany tend to be quite strict with these things. Entering Peru and Paraguay could also be complicated (assuming you are a citizen of one of them, at the very list the other country).

Comment: Are you asking about going to Peru/Paraguay or coming back to Germany? What country are you a citizen of? Marking as unclear until you specify.

Comment: To rephrase @Relaxed's comment somewhat: even a *valid* German residence card would be insufficient documentation for this trip (or most likely for any flight external to the Schengen zone).  You need a valid passport.

Comment: @mts the question may be unclear, but the answer is clearly *no* in any case, as Relaxed has mentioned in his comment.

Comment: @phoog no doubt about that, even though the embassy put a stamp into it making it valid again, putting the passport into a weird (quantum?!) superposition of valid and invalid - or a Zombie/undead passport if you prefer (but I'm not so fluent in the lingo there) - i.e. it is not Schrödinger's cat but Schrödingers passport. And from Q I deduce the Germans don't do quantum passporting and the residence card remains invalid (what about the permit) and OP is advised to avoid any type of passport control at all cost until he gets his documents in order. Was just wondering if it's better for Expats.

Comment: Am latino so I can go to peru Paraguay  for Xmas and I can enter the Schengen for 90 days as a tourist

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Not without a valid passport, you can't.  Even to enter the Schengen zone, the passport must have been issued within the previous 10 years, so if you have an extended passport that was originally valid for 10 years, you can't use it to enter as a tourist.  If it was extended after a five-year period of validity you might be able to do that.

Comment: Passports are 5 years valid only in my country... and if the passport gets an "another year" extension? ? Then IT IS A VALID PASSPORT , don't you think?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ In that case then yes, it is a valid passport and should also be acceptable for entry into the Schengen area.  You could mention the passport's date of issue in your question to make the question clearer.  The question is better suited to [Expatriates.SE], however, since the central question concerns your status in Germany as a long-term resident.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot travel outside the Schengen area without a valid passport. Likewise you cannot enter the Schengen area without a valid visa, unless your passport allows you visa-free entry into the Schengen area.

Comment: what about the fact that the embassy just put a stamp on my old expired passport making it valid for another year, then I can go out and in...